# Convert type (of primitive) back to primitive in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a custom type in OCaml:

```
type d = DefaultTemplateDir | TemplateDir of string
```

And later on in the program I apply this:

```
let get_full_name ?(template_dir: d = DefaultTemplateDir) file_name =
    let dir = (match template_dir with
    | DefaultTemplateDir -> ""
    | TemplateDir custom_dir -> custom_dir) in
    dir ^ file_name
```

But I get an error here:

```
This expression has type d but an expression was expected of type string.
```

How do I convert my TemplateDir type back to a string so I can do string operations on it?

Comment: The code works for me, where is your type error located exactly ?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Not sure why there was an error here. Fiddled around with some other things and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct. You need to call it as

```
get_full_name ~template_dir:(TemplateDir "template-dir") "file-name"
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. It just started working after messing around with some other errors. My bad! I was about to delete the question when you answered. Thanks!